# How to animate material alpha property via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating Animator OverrideController via script based on current controller assigned to animator component. I have created animation curve for position and it works. When i try to animate transparency (material color alpha) it does not work. Did I fail to properly access this property?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimationScript : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();

        AnimationCurve curve = AnimationCurve.EaseInOut(0.0f, transform.position.x, 1.0f, transform.position.x);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition.x", curve);

        curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Material), "_Color.a", curve);

        Animator anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        AnimatorOverrideController animatorOverrideController = new AnimatorOverrideController(anim.runtimeAnimatorController);
        // "loop" is the name of clip not name of state
        animatorOverrideController["loop"] = clip;
        anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animatorOverrideController;
    }

}
```

However analogous code for legacy Animation component works:

```
void Start()
{
    Animation anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    AnimationCurve curve;

    // create a new AnimationClip
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    clip.legacy = true;

    // update the clip to a change color
    curve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
    clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Material), "_Color.a", curve);

    // now animate the GameObject
    anim.AddClip(clip, clip.name);
    anim.Play(clip.name);
}
```

What am I missing and why is first script not working?

Comment: is your material set to transparent (i.e does it fade when you change color alpha manually?)

Comment: Yes. Rendering mode is set to transparent and it fades when I change alpha value of albedo color manually. But if I do the same in play mode it remains opaque.